# How to make second tabbarItem to be selected as default in iPhone?

Tags: xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have added a UITabBarController programatically (Search,Login) and I want to set second tabbaritem(Login) and its view to be selected  when Login credentials are not correct.But I m unable to do it so ..Could not understand where I m going wrong ..?

```
    Search *first = [[Search alloc] initWithNibName:@"Search" bundle:nil];
    first.title=@"Search";
    Login *second=[[Login alloc]initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
    second.title=@"Login";
    NSArray *viewArray= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:first,second, nil];
    tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewArray animated:NO]; 
    [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2]; 
    [self presentModalViewController:tabBarController animated:NO];
```

But here my SearchViewController is selected and displayed as default...Where i m going wrong..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is in this line:

```
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```

Counting starts not from 1 but from 0, so in your case you have to change it to:

```
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Comment: I tried ur code .But still Imm getting the first ViewController set as default ..How can I do it ...?

Comment: Do you create and init tabBarController in appDelegate? If not, create and init your tabBarController only in your appDelegate.

Comment: Yes I have this Appdelegate.m  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
        
 Search *first = [[Search alloc] initWithNibName:@"Search" bundle:nil];
first.title=@"Search";
Login *second=[[Login alloc]initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
second.title=@"Login";
NSArray *viewArray= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:first,second, nil];tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];[tabBarController setViewControllers:viewArray animated:NO]; 
[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];

Comment: [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];[viewArray release];[first release];[second release];return YES;} I have done this .What elz should I do ?